# Excluding feature classes from list using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, buffer, feature-class

I'm new to Python and trying to buffer some feature classes within a list in a Geodatabase. I used the Clip* wildcard to select the files, but I want to exclude three of those files, so I don't use the buffer on them. I tried the `if not fc.startswith('Clip_blabla')` but it won't run, as it says invalid syntax. Any ideas?

```
fcList = [arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("Clip*") if not fc.startswith('Clip_blabla')]

#Create a loop to buffer Clip*
bufferList = []

for fc in fcList:
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(fc, fc + "Buff", "700 Meters", "", "", "ALL") 
    #Add each buffer feature class to a list of feature classes 
    bufferList.append(fc + "Buff") 
    print(fc + "Buff") 
    if fc == "ClipProjMelb_UrbanRes":
        break
```

Comment: Your attempt at a list comprehension doesn't follow the use pattern for a comprehension, so yes there is a syntax error in line one (which also means you don't need lines 2-12 in the question). The generic syntax is `[ expression for item in list if conditional ]` so you're missing the `fc for fc in`

Comment: Thankyou for including lines 2-12 in your question, as it provides some greatly appreciated context around which to form a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to remember the convoluted syntax for list comprehensions **or** don't use it all:

```
fcList = [arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("Clip*")]

#Create a loop to buffer Clip*
bufferList = []

for fc in fcList:
    if not fc.startswith('Clip_blabla'):
        arcpy.Buffer_analysis(fc, fc + "Buff", "700 Meters", "", "", "ALL") 
        #Add each buffer feature class to a list of feature classes 
        bufferList.append(fc + "Buff") 
        print(fc + "Buff") 
        if fc == "ClipProjMelb_UrbanRes":
            break
```

you could even implement an *omit_list*[] to statically define every single omission:

```
fcList = [arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("Clip*")]

#define omit_list[]
omit_list = ['omit_this_one','omit_that_one','omit_me_too']

#Create a loop to buffer Clip*
bufferList = []

for fc in fcList:
    if not fc in omit_list:
        arcpy.Buffer_analysis(fc, fc + "Buff", "700 Meters", "", "", "ALL") 
        #Add each buffer feature class to a list of feature classes 
        bufferList.append(fc + "Buff") 
        print(fc + "Buff") 
        if fc == "ClipProjMelb_UrbanRes":
            break
```

Glad you included enough code to completely demonstrate these alternative implementation patterns. I too didn't feel like looking up the proper syntax for implementing a list comprehension, but for those who do :

[List Comprehensions in Python @ pythonforbeginners](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)